# Comparing PropertyPath values

Tags: c#, windows-phone-7, animation

I have this problem that I can't seem to get over. Maybe someone can help.

I'm creating a method to dynamically create DoubleAnimations. I would feed it an array of different user controls from an array and it will automatically create DoubleAnimations to add to a StoryBoard.

The thing is, I need to insert two types of PropertyPaths: *PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty* and *Control.OpacityProperty*. I must set *Storyboard.SetTarget* differently for them so I'll need a way to compare the PropertyPath argument which i call TargetProperty in my method. To explain here's a part of what I'm trying to do in code:

```
if (TargetProperty == new PropertyPath (PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty))
{
    // Do some code
    projection = control.Projection as PlaneProjection;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, projection);
}
else if (TargetProperty == new PropertyPath (Control.OpacityProperty))
{
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, control);
}
```

I was able to make my method work by using a bool as a workaround switch but I still would prefer to reduce the number of arguments in my method if it's possible.

I've tried using:

```
if (TargetProperty.ToString() == new PropertyPath (PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty).ToString())
```

... and...

```
if (TargetProperty.Equals(new PropertyPath (PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty)))
```

... but none of them worked. Any ideas to get around this? Am I doing something wrong?

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Do you need `control` to create the `doubleAnimation`, or is it just used for `Storyboard.SetTarget`?

Comment: `control` could be any user control that I want animated. `projection` is the `PlaneProjection` of that very same control. Yes, it is used only for the `Storyboard.SetTarget`.

My method originally handled both the control's plane projection and opacity properties at the same time but I thought I'd try to make it work with just one so that I can reduce the number of arguments that I need to pass to it. That's when I noticed this little quirk. I've been thinking about using the old method again but I thought it would be interesting to know if there are any ways around this first.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

After KooKiz suggested that I use `DependencyObject` I realized that I can use `DependencyProperty` instead of the `PropertyPath` which I then try to compare. As mentioned by nmclean, it seems like comparing `PropertyPath` objects is impossible - at least in my case it is. My code then became something like this and it now works like a charm:

```
if (TargetProperty == PlaneProjection.RotationYProperty)
{
    // Do some code
    projection = control.Projection as PlaneProjection;
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, projection);
}
else if (TargetProperty == Control.OpacityProperty)
{
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, control);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

First of all, couldn't you redesign the system so that the argument is just the property? Do everything you need to do with the property first, *then* generate the `PropertyPath` and assign it to the animation.

<del>Until then, you could try comparing the `Path` property:

    if (TargetProperty.Path == new PropertyPath(dependencyProperty).Path)</del>

---

OK, looks like `Path` will only match if the `PropertyPath` was created by passing a string into the constructor.

There is another way to compare them in WPF, but it's not available in Silverlight: The path data is in an array called `PathParameters` which will have matching elements between two instances of `PropertyPath` which were created by passing the same dependency property to their constructors. Silverlight doesn't give you access to `PathParameters`, so unless there's another helper method somewhere (I looked at [PropertyPathConverter](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-CA/library/system.windows.propertypathconverter%28v=vs.95%29.aspx) but it doesn't look like it will help), your only option (other than reflection) is to eliminate the need to compare paths.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion. Unfortunately, this also doesn't seem to work.

As for redesigning the system, the original method actually handled both projection and opacity properties at the same time but I thought I'd make it work with just one (by running it twice for each property) since it's basically doing most of the same thing anyway. I'm already thinking of bringing back parts of the former system so that there would be no need to compare the paths anymore but, as mentioned in a comment I wrote under my post, I thought it would be interesting to know if there are ways around this first.

Comment: @DeVilFisCh Alright, I think I've gotten to the bottom of it, but it looks like you're still out of luck... see my edit.

Comment: Fortunately, KooKiz's answer pointed me to the right direction. I have found the simplest solution to my problem - use `DependencyProperty` instead. I can compare it which I need to do and I can use it on `SetTargetProperty` as well. Still, thanks you for your suggestions.

Answer (score 0):

If you're using the same logic to create the animation in both cases, pass directly the target property to your method:

```
public void AssignAnimation(DependencyObject property)
{
    // Create the doubleAnimation
    // ...

    // Assign it
    Storyboard.SetTarget(doubleAnimation, property);
}
```

Then you just have to call it directly with your property:

```
AssignAnimation(control);
AssignAnimation(control.Projection);
```

If you're using different logics, then I'd suggest just going with two separate methods. Your code will be easier to read and maintain.

Comment: Because I need to animate different properties I originally used the `PropertyPath` as an argument for my method which is then set as the `SetTargetProperty` but thanks to your answer I figured out that I could use `DependencyProperty` instead which can be compared and still be set as the `PropertyPath`. Thanks a lot!